# Code Challenge: basic arithmic operations using only incrementation operator

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, recursion, reinventing-the-wheel, calculator

**Challenge**

> Write a function that takes 2 integer operands `left` and `right`
>   (both >= 0) and evaluates one of the following basic arithmic
>   operations:
>
> - addition
> - multiplication
> - exponentation
>
> The challenge is you are prohibited from using any built-in operator,
>   except for an incrementation (`++` or `+1`). The entropy is all
>   results that are in bounds of the maximum value of an integer.

**Provided Classes**

```
public enum Operation
{
    Addition,
    Multiplication,
    Exponentation
}

public static class Expression
{
    public static int Evaluate(int left, int right, Operation operation)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // .. this should be implemented
    }
}
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestClass]
public class Fixtures
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Fixture()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(5, Expression.Evaluate(2, 3, Operation.Addition));
        Assert.AreEqual(6, Expression.Evaluate(2, 3, Operation.Multiplication));
        Assert.AreEqual(8, Expression.Evaluate(2, 3, Operation.Exponentation));
    }
}
```

**My Solution**

I have decided to use the *hyperoperation* ([Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation)). The only arithmic operator used is in the first branch (`if (n == 0)` -> `b + 1`).

> $$ H_n(a,b) = a[n]b = 
>  \begin{cases}
>                        b + 1 & \text{if } n = 0 \\
>                            a & \text{if } n = 1 \text{ and } b = 0 \\
>                            0 & \text{if } n = 2 \text{ and } b = 0 \\
>                            1 & \text{if } n \ge 3 \text{ and } b = 0 \\
>    H_{n-1}(a, H_n(a, b - 1)) & \text{otherwise}
>  \end{cases}$$

And my implementation of `Evaluate`:

```
public static class Expression
{
    public static int Evaluate(int left, int right, Operation operation)
    {
        return Hyper(left, (int)operation + 1, right);
    }

    static int Hyper(int a, int n, int b)
    {
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation
        // a = left operand   (a >= 0)
        // n = hyper operator (n >= 0)
        // b = right operand  (b >= 0)

        if (a < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(a));
        if (b < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(b));
        if (n < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n));
        if (n == 0) return b + 1;
        if (b == 0) return n == 1 ? a : n == 2 ? 0 : 1;

        return Hyper(a, n - 1, Hyper(a, n, b - 1));
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Are there any overlooked flaws in my solution?
- Could this be optimized for performance?
- Are there perhaps better alternatives, and why would they be better?
- Any general review of my code, style, conventions are invited.

Comment: I have tried to fix the quoted TeX block. Please check if it still  correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> public enum Operation
> {
>     Addition,
>     Multiplication,
>     Exponentation
> }
> ```

If you gave these explicit values:

```
  public enum Operation
  {
    Addition = 1,
    Multiplication = 2,
    Exponentation = 3
  }
```

... you could avoid the `+ 1` for the operation:

```
  return Hyper(left, (int)operation, right);
```

---

Because `Hyper(...)` is private, and you are supposed to know how to use it, there is no need for checking the input values in there. It is safe to leave it to `Evaluate(...)` to do that:

```
public static int Evaluate(int left, int right, Operation operation)
{
  if (left < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(left));
  if (right < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(right));
  if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Operation), operation)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(operation));

  return Hyper(left, (int)operation, right);
}
```

it is safe because:

```
  if (n == 0) return b + 1;
  if (b == 0) return n == 1 ? a : n == 2 ? 0 : 1;
```

will catch zeros for `n` and `b` while `a` never changes so no arguments will never be lesser than zero - as you can only decrement by one.

---

Personally I would change the order of `b` and `n` to be the same as for `Evaluate(...)`:

```
static int Hyper(int a, int b, int n) {...}
```

---

All in all in my writing it would look like:

```
  public enum Operation
  {
    Addition = 1,
    Multiplication = 2,
    Exponentation = 3
  }

  public static class Expression
  {
    public static int Evaluate(int left, int right, Operation operation)
    {
      if (left < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(left));
      if (right < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(right));
      if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Operation), operation)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(operation));

      return Hyper(left, right, (int)operation);
    }

    static int Hyper(int a, int b, int n)
    {
      if (n == 0) return b + 1;
      if (b == 0) return n == 1 ? a : n == 2 ? 0 : 1;

      return Hyper(a, Hyper(a, b - 1, n), n - 1);
    }
  }
```

---

More edge/test cases?

---

BtW `Hyper()` stack overflows relatively quickly: for instance for `a == 8` and `b == 5` for `Exponentation`.

An alternative algorithm could be the below "semi-recurs-iterative":

It has a recursive depth of max 3:

```
public static int HyperIter(int a, int b, int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
  {
    while (b > 0)
    {
      a++;
      b--;
    }

    return a;
  }
  else
  {
    int res = n - 1;
    res--;
    while (b > 0)
    {
      res = HyperIter(res, a, n - 1);
      b--;
    }

    return res;
  }
}
```

I'm though not sure if it completely satisfies the criteria of only using `+ 1`, because it uses a local variable (`res`) and `--` - but the original also uses `- 1` in the recursive calls, so...?

Comment: You are right, I should only check those args once, at the top level.

Comment: Now you mention it, the decrementaton should be allowed as well. I won't update the question. It would invalidate your answer for a part. And perhaps there is a possibility of using only incrementation..

Answer (score 2):

That is an elegant implementation using the hyperoperation. The disadvantage is that a branch on the “level” is needed in each recursive step.

I would implement the addition, multiplication and exponentiation as *separate* functions. That makes the level parameter obsolete. It is more code but (in my opinion) much clearer:

```
public static int Evaluate(int left, int right, Operation operation)
{
    if (left < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(left));
    if (right < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(right));

    switch (operation)
    {
        case Operation.Addition:
            return Add(left, right);
        case Operation.Multiplication:
            return Mult(left, right);
        case Operation.Exponentation:
            return Power(left, right);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(operation));
    }
}

static int Add(int a, int b) {
    // a + 0 = a
    if (b == 0) { return a; }

    // a + b = (a + 1) + (b - 1)
    return Add(a + 1, b - 1);
}

static int Mult(int a, int b) {
    // a * 0 = 0
    if (b == 0) { return 0; }

    // a * b = a * (b - 1) + a
    return Add(Mult(a, b - 1), a);
}

static int Power(int a, int b) {
    // a^0 = 1
    if (b == 0) { return 1; }

    // a^b = a^(b-1) * a
    return Mult(Power(a, b - 1), a);
}
```

It is also considerably faster than the original implementation. My results (tested with [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com) on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook) for computing

```
Expression.Evaluate(7, 6, Operation.Exponentation)
```

- Original code: 9.5 seconds
- Above code: 0.05 seconds

Comment: This is a valid solution, well split into sub routines, using the hyper operator. I am surprised the difference in performance is that high. :o

Comment: This is essentially the same concept as my suggestion.

Comment: @HenrikHansen: My suggestion was to replace the single Hyper(a, b, n) function by 3 functions Add/Mult/Power(a, b) which do *not* take a level parameter (and therefore do not branch on the level). I do not see that concept in your answer. If that is what you meant then please believe me that it was not my intention to copy your idea.

Comment: I didn't mean to accuse you of stealing anything :-), my point is just, that the concept of `Power` calls `Mult` and `Mult` calls `Add` is essentially what I'm doing. Feel free to copy, steal or what ever you like - we are helping each other to improved code here :-)

Comment: BtW: when I run the original code with (7, 6, Exponentation) I get a stackoverflow exception. Are you running it in a thread with an expanded stack size?

Comment: @HenrikHansen: I am using Mono (https://www.mono-project.com) on macOS. That might behave differently from C# on Windows.